# how to make safecracker login form open in a new window/tab

Tags: templates, safecracker, members

I currently have a safecracker login form which enables specific users to login and download files. [click here][1] I have noticed when a user logs in they are redirected to the following link [click here][2], however the link loads in the same window. Is there a way to do this where once the user has logged in an a new window/tab is created with the download credentials? Below is a snippet of my `return=` code.

```
{exp:member:login_form return="press/promo/{segment_3}"}
```

Comment: the return can't open new windows. However you can return to a page that uses javascript to do the opening of a new window with the promo-page.

Comment: You can submit the pop-up login form with Ajax and can open download in new window/tab with JavaScript.

Comment: @BhashkarYadav can you elaborate on this please,

Comment: @NewBoy Sure, I posted answer with example code. Hope, it would help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have easy approach by using "jQuery Form Plugin" (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). To get some better ideas see the examples. For the Ajax submit you can use the code like:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var options = {
beforeSubmit : function(){},
success : function(data, status, oo){
window.open ('[URL]', '[Window Title]');
}
}; 
$('#FORM_ID').ajaxForm(options);
});
```

See within the success function, window.open will open the given URL in new window. For more about window.open take a reference from http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Hope, it would help you.